# Merge tags "volume" and "trading-volume"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Tags [volume](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volume) and [trading-volume](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trading-volume) are about the same thing. Should they be merged?

Comment: `volume` doesn't even have a description with it.

Comment: I set up the synonym.